# python mac/windows computation issue

Tags: python, scipy, operating-system

i'm running the following python function on a mac and a pc and get different results. what it does it to fit my data to a sine wave. python 3.8.5, scipy 1.6.2. the function and dataset are not copies, they are the same from a shared folder.

```
def fit_bt(data_c):

N = 15000  # len(data)  # number of data points
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
u_d = [-1] * len(data_c)
slope = [0] * len(data_c)
curve = [0] * len(data_c)

guess_mean = np.mean(data_c[0:N])
guess_phase = 0
guess_freq = 0.9
guess_amp = 1

for i in range(N, len(data_c), 5):
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(i)
    data_t = data_c[i-N:i]
    

    optimize_func = lambda x: x[0]*np.sin(x[1]*t+x[2]) + x[3] - data_t
    est_amp, est_freq, est_phase, est_mean = leastsq(optimize_func, [guess_amp, guess_freq, guess_phase, guess_mean])[0]

    data_fit = est_amp * np.sin(est_freq * t + est_phase) + est_mean
    if (len(data_c)-i) > 5: 
        u_d[i:i+5] = [(data_fit[-1] > data_fit[-2]) for val in range(5)]
        slope[i:i+5] = [((data_fit[-1] - data_fit[-10]) * 10000) for val in range(5)]
        curve[i:i+5] = [data_fit[-1] for val in range(5)]

    guess_mean = est_mean
    guess_phase = est_phase
    guess_freq = est_freq
    guess_amp = est_amp

return u_d, slope, curve
```

when i plot the slope result i get:

result mac:

[image]

result pc:

[image]

why do i get different results on different os? on each os the result is constant after each run.

Comment: seems like some data values are getting changed. i would suggest comparing your data.u_d between two runs if data is same and graph are different then for a sure issue with the plot.

Comment: to make it clear, every run on the mac gives the same results, and every run on the pc gives the same results. i also use the same ide on both platform

Comment: `scipy` wheels for `macosx` and `win32` are different. I had issues too between `macosx` and `linux`.

Comment: i ran the same code on linux and i get the same result as on a mac.